# Restrict input value from paste with regex in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have input field to place a phone number and i want to restrict every special character like

> +,- .

from my input field with onPaste event.
My code below is not working, i still can paste those special character to my input field

```
onPaste(e) {
  let str = e.target.value;
  let newstr = str.replace(/[+-.]/g, '');
  if (str !== newstr) {
  e.preventDefault();
 }}
```

my input code

```
<InputText
  name="officePhone"
  placeholder="Office Phone"
  label="Office Phone"
  type="number"
  onChange={e => this.onChange(e, 'form')}
  value={this.state.form.officePhone}
  onPaste={e => this.onPaste(e)}
/>
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: my code above is not working , i still able to paste those special character to my input field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `onPaste` function is looking at the `e.target.value`,  what it needs to be getting is the pasted data from the clipboard which you get by using `e.clipboardData.getData('Text')`.

```
onPaste(e) {
  const str = e.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  const newStr = str.replace(/[+-.]/g, '');
  if (str !== newStr) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `onPaste(e)` function also change the component state? Since the value of `<InputField />` is set to `this.state.form.officePhone`

Comment: I am assuming he/she will come across this and add it to state later.  I am unaware of how he/she is implementing the logic in the bigger picture.

Comment: @JustinOber getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'detData' of undefined"